# How to make an AlertDialog in Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-alertdialog

I am learning to build apps in Flutter. Now I have come to alert dialogs. I have done them before in [Android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43513920/3681880) and [iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33340757/3681880), but how do I make an alert in Flutter?

Here are some related SO questions:

- [How to style AlertDialog Actions in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51235014/how-to-style-alertdialog-actions-in-flutter)
- [adding dropdown menu in alert dialog box in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52526591/adding-dropdown-menu-in-alert-dialog-box-in-flutter)
- [Show alert dialog on app main screen load automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52164369/show-alert-dialog-on-app-main-screen-load-automatically)
- [how to refresh alertdialog in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51962272/how-to-refresh-alertdialog-in-flutter)
- [Alert Dialog with Rounded corners in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50964365/alert-dialog-with-rounded-corners-in-flutter)

I'd like to make a more general canonical Q&A so my answer is below.

Comment: The Best way to use alert dialog is to create a separate class for the alert dialog and use it in the entire project. Refer this : https://arkapp.medium.com/how-to-use-alert-dialog-in-flutter-a5637346d984

Comment: Here's a customizable dialog: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77432996/7389293

Answer (score 356, accepted):

## One Button

[image]

```
showAlertDialog(BuildContext context) {

  // set up the button
  Widget okButton = TextButton(
    child: Text("OK"),
    onPressed: () { },
  );

  // set up the AlertDialog
  AlertDialog alert = AlertDialog(
    title: Text("My title"),
    content: Text("This is my message."),
    actions: [
      okButton,
    ],
  );

  // show the dialog
  showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return alert;
    },
  );
}
```

## Two Buttons

[image]

```
showAlertDialog(BuildContext context) {

  // set up the buttons
  Widget cancelButton = TextButton(
    child: Text("Cancel"),
    onPressed:  () {},
  );
  Widget continueButton = TextButton(
    child: Text("Continue"),
    onPressed:  () {},
  );

  // set up the AlertDialog
  AlertDialog alert = AlertDialog(
    title: Text("AlertDialog"),
    content: Text("Would you like to continue learning how to use Flutter alerts?"),
    actions: [
      cancelButton,
      continueButton,
    ],
  );

  // show the dialog
  showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return alert;
    },
  );
}
```

## Three Buttons

[image]

```
showAlertDialog(BuildContext context) {

  // set up the buttons
  Widget remindButton = TextButton(
    child: Text("Remind me later"),
    onPressed:  () {},
  );
  Widget cancelButton = TextButton(
    child: Text("Cancel"),
    onPressed:  () {},
  );
  Widget launchButton = TextButton(
    child: Text("Launch missile"),
    onPressed:  () {},
  );

  // set up the AlertDialog
  AlertDialog alert = AlertDialog(
    title: Text("Notice"),
    content: Text("Launching this missile will destroy the entire universe. Is this what you intended to do?"),
    actions: [
      remindButton,
      cancelButton,
      launchButton,
    ],
  );

  // show the dialog
  showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return alert;
    },
  );
}
```

## Handling button presses

The `onPressed` callback for the buttons in the examples above were empty, but you could add something like this:

```
Widget launchButton = TextButton(
  child: Text("Launch missile"),
  onPressed:  () {
    Navigator.of(context).pop(); // dismiss dialog
    launchMissile();
  },
);
```

If you make the callback `null`, then the button will be disabled.

```
onPressed: null,
```

[image]

## Supplemental code

Here is the code for `main.dart` in case you weren't getting the functions above to run.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Flutter'),
        ),
        body: MyLayout()),
    );
  }
}

class MyLayout extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: ElevatedButton(
        child: Text('Show alert'),
        onPressed: () {
          showAlertDialog(context);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

// replace this function with the examples above
showAlertDialog(BuildContext context) { ... }
```

Comment: Navigator.of(context).pop(); does not dismiss the dialog, but the screen beneath it. The dialog presists.

Comment: @GunJack, It sounds like you are using a different setup than I have here. There is only a single screen in the example here.

Comment: Yeah I think because I using multiple navigators. Calling showDialog directly in the button's onPressed method works. But calling showAlertDialog function from onPressed makes for the weird behaviour.

Comment: I tried this and the code after `showAlertDialog` runs immediately after the dialog pops up and doesnt wait for the choice to be done. How can I ensure the next code runs after a choice is selected? I tried using await and still no luck

Comment: @West, put the code that you want to run afterward in the `onPressed` callback of the dialog button.

Comment: Great answer!
Also if you want to build your own custom dialog you can do it by using `Dialog` widget. It is as the same as above answer, but instead of using `AlertDialog` this class can return any custom widget that you build so it will be displayed as the popup.
Read more in this [medium article](https://medium.com/flutterdevs/custom-dialog-in-flutter-7ca5c2a8d33a)

Comment: Do I need to have bool state implementation in all widgets that needs to show the dialog component?

Comment: @lolelo, what do you mean by bool state implementation?

Comment: @Suragch I missed that `showDialog` was a method from the `package:flutter/src/material/dialog.dart`.
I thought I had to do conditional rendering to show the dialog.

Comment: on Tap OK Button use  Navigator.pop(context);  For Go Back

Comment: I'm getting this warning: The declaration `showAlertDialog` isn't referenced. Which results in dialog not showing up on Tap, how can I fix this?

Comment: Launching this missile will destroy the entire universe. Is this what you intended to do? -- did you press the Launch missile Button at last ?

Answer (score 42):

I used similar approach, but I wanted to

1. Keep the Dialog code as a widget in a separated file so **I can reuse it**.
2. Blurr the background when the dialog is shown.

[image]

Code:
1. `alertDialog_widget.dart`

```
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


class BlurryDialog extends StatelessWidget {

  String title;
  String content;
  VoidCallback continueCallBack;

  BlurryDialog(this.title, this.content, this.continueCallBack);
  TextStyle textStyle = TextStyle (color: Colors.black);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BackdropFilter(
      filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 6, sigmaY: 6),
      child:  AlertDialog(
      title: new Text(title,style: textStyle,),
      content: new Text(content, style: textStyle,),
      actions: <Widget>[
        new FlatButton(
          child: new Text("Continue"),
           onPressed: () {
            continueCallBack();
          },
        ),
        new FlatButton(
          child: Text("Cancel"),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
          },
        ),
      ],
      ));
  }
}
```

You can call this in main (or wherever you want) by creating a new method like:

```
 _showDialog(BuildContext context)
{

  VoidCallback continueCallBack = () => {
 Navigator.of(context).pop(),
    // code on continue comes here

  };
  BlurryDialog  alert = BlurryDialog("Abort","Are you sure you want to abort this operation?",continueCallBack);


  showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return alert;
    },
  );
}
```

Comment: You need to remove the dialog after user choose Continue option. So I needed to add  Navigator.of(context).pop(); after continueCallback()

Comment: @ReginaldoRigo yes. I had to add it in my code as well. Just added it to the answer.

Comment: This worked for me but I had to convert BlurryDialog to a StatefulWidget and declare the 2 Strings and VoidCallback as finals.

Comment: How to alert error dialog using StatelessWidget?

Comment: I added working version of this below in 2023 without changing it to Stateful Widget

Answer (score 23):

You can use this code snippet for creating a two buttoned Alert box,

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class BaseAlertDialog extends StatelessWidget {

  //When creating please recheck 'context' if there is an error!

  Color _color = Color.fromARGB(220, 117, 218 ,255);

  String _title;
  String _content;
  String _yes;
  String _no;
  Function _yesOnPressed;
  Function _noOnPressed;

  BaseAlertDialog({String title, String content, Function yesOnPressed, Function noOnPressed, String yes = "Yes", String no = "No"}){
    this._title = title;
    this._content = content;
    this._yesOnPressed = yesOnPressed;
    this._noOnPressed = noOnPressed;
    this._yes = yes;
    this._no = no;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      title: new Text(this._title),
      content: new Text(this._content),
      backgroundColor: this._color,
      shape:
          RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(15)),
      actions: <Widget>[
        new FlatButton(
          child: new Text(this._yes),
          textColor: Colors.greenAccent,
          onPressed: () {
            this._yesOnPressed();
          },
        ),
        new FlatButton(
          child: Text(this._no),
          textColor: Colors.redAccent,
          onPressed: () {
            this._noOnPressed();
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

To show the dialog you can have a method that calls it NB after importing `BaseAlertDialog`  class

```
_confirmRegister() {
var baseDialog = BaseAlertDialog(
    title: "Confirm Registration",
    content: "I Agree that the information provided is correct",
    yesOnPressed: () {},
    noOnPressed: () {},
    yes: "Agree",
    no: "Cancel");
showDialog(context: context, builder: (BuildContext context) => baseDialog);
}
```

***OUTPUT WILL BE LIKE THIS***

[image: Output]

Comment: How do I call this on an onTap function?

Comment: In Suragch's answer above, he has provided all the code to make an example app, where you tap the button and the dialog shows.

Answer (score 22):

Here is a shorter, but complete code.

If you need a dialog with only one button:

```
await showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => new AlertDialog(
        title: new Text('Message'),
        content: Text(
                'Your file is saved.'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          new FlatButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true)
                  .pop(); // dismisses only the dialog and returns nothing
            },
            child: new Text('OK'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

If you need a dialog with Yes/No buttons:

```
onPressed: () async {
bool result = await showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      title: Text('Confirmation'),
      content: Text('Do you want to save?'),
      actions: <Widget>[
        new FlatButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true)
                .pop(false); // dismisses only the dialog and returns false
          },
          child: Text('No'),
        ),
        FlatButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true)
                .pop(true); // dismisses only the dialog and returns true
          },
          child: Text('Yes'),
        ),
      ],
    );
  },
);

if (result) {
  if (missingvalue) {
    Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(new SnackBar(
      content: new Text('Missing Value'),
    ));
  } else {
    saveObject();
    Navigator.of(context).pop(_myObject); // dismisses the entire widget
  }
} else {
  Navigator.of(context).pop(_myObject); // dismisses the entire widget
}
}
```

Answer (score 17):

Simply used this custom dialog class which field you not needed to leave it or make it null so this customization you got easily.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomAlertDialog extends StatelessWidget {
  final Color bgColor;
  final String title;
  final String message;
  final String positiveBtnText;
  final String negativeBtnText;
  final Function onPostivePressed;
  final Function onNegativePressed;
  final double circularBorderRadius;

  CustomAlertDialog({
    this.title,
    this.message,
    this.circularBorderRadius = 15.0,
    this.bgColor = Colors.white,
    this.positiveBtnText,
    this.negativeBtnText,
    this.onPostivePressed,
    this.onNegativePressed,
  })  : assert(bgColor != null),
        assert(circularBorderRadius != null);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      title: title != null ? Text(title) : null,
      content: message != null ? Text(message) : null,
      backgroundColor: bgColor,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(circularBorderRadius)),
      actions: <Widget>[
        negativeBtnText != null
            ? FlatButton(
                child: Text(negativeBtnText),
                textColor: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  if (onNegativePressed != null) {
                    onNegativePressed();
                  }
                },
              )
            : null,
        positiveBtnText != null
            ? FlatButton(
                child: Text(positiveBtnText),
                textColor: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                onPressed: () {
                  if (onPostivePressed != null) {
                    onPostivePressed();
                  }
                },
              )
            : null,
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
var dialog = CustomAlertDialog(
  title: "Logout",
  message: "Are you sure, do you want to logout?",
  onPostivePressed: () {},
  positiveBtnText: 'Yes',
  negativeBtnText: 'No');
showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (BuildContext context) => dialog);
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 12):

Minumum code for alert dialog

```
showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (_) => AlertDialog(
    title: Text('Title'),
    content: Text(
      'Content widget',
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 9):

Or you can use RFlutter Alert library for that. It is easily customizable and easy-to-use. Its default style includes rounded corners and you can add buttons as much as you want.

Basic Alert:

```
Alert(context: context, title: "RFLUTTER", desc: "Flutter is awesome.").show();
```

Alert with Button:

```
Alert(
    context: context,
    type: AlertType.error,
    title: "RFLUTTER ALERT",
    desc: "Flutter is more awesome with RFlutter Alert.",
    buttons: [
    DialogButton(
        child: Text(
        "COOL",
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
        ),
        onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
        width: 120,
    )
    ],
).show();
```

You can also define [generic alert styles](https://github.com/RatelHub/rflutter_alert#alert-with-style).

*I'm one of developer of RFlutter Alert.

Comment: Nice. Looks like it could save some boilerplate and is pretty customizable.

Comment: Is there a way to pass different functions to the onPressed parameter of the Alert so I don't have to keep making new alerts for everything??

Answer (score 5):

If you want beautiful and responsive alert dialog then you can use flutter packages like

**rflutter alert ,fancy dialog,rich alert,sweet alert dialogs,easy dialog & easy alert**

These alerts are good looking and responsive. Among them rflutter alert is the best. currently I am using rflutter alert for my apps.

Comment: links along with package names would be helpful

Comment: I'm developer RFlutter Alert and thanks for your nice comment @raman raman .

Answer (score 5):

```
showAlertDialog(BuildContext context, String message, String heading,
      String buttonAcceptTitle, String buttonCancelTitle) {
    // set up the buttons
    Widget cancelButton = FlatButton(
      child: Text(buttonCancelTitle),
      onPressed: () {},
    );
    Widget continueButton = FlatButton(
      child: Text(buttonAcceptTitle),
      onPressed: () {

      },
    );

    // set up the AlertDialog
    AlertDialog alert = AlertDialog(
      title: Text(heading),
      content: Text(message),
      actions: [
        cancelButton,
        continueButton,
      ],
    );

    // show the dialog
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return alert;
      },
    );
  }
```

called like:

```
showAlertDialog(context, 'Are you sure you want to delete?', "AppName" , "Ok", "Cancel");
```

Answer (score 3):

Check out [Flutter Dropdown Banner](https://pub.dev/packages/dropdown_banner) to easily alert users of events and prompt action without having to manage the complexity of presenting, delaying, and dismissing the component.

#### To set it up:

```
import 'packages:dropdown_banner/dropdown_banner.dart';
...
class MainApp extends StatelessWidget {
  ...
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
    ...
    return MaterialApp(
        ...
        home: DropdownBanner(
          child: Scaffold(...),
          navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

#### To use it:

```
import 'packages:dropdown_banner/dropdown_banner.dart';
...
class SomeClass {
  ...
  void doSomethingThenFail() {
    DropdownBanner.showBanner(
      text: 'Failed to complete network request',
      color: Colors.red,
      textStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
    );
  }
}
```

Click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijUkB.gif) to see an example

Comment: When posting links as answers, try to add some actual text/code to explain why you gave the link, and/or how to use the linked content. Otherwise, such replies should be comments.

Comment: @Adrian I added some example code as per your recommendation.

Answer (score 2):

If you need a dialog so this code for you. just use `showMyDialog()` `onPress` or  any inside a function.

```
 void showMyDialog() {
  showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (ctx) => AlertDialog(
    title: const Text("Login Failed!"),
    content: const Text(
      "Invalid credential !! Please check your email or password",
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
    ),
    actions: <Widget>[
      TextButton(
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.of(ctx).pop();
        },
        child: Container(
          child: const Text(
            "Try again",
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.cyan, fontSize: 17),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
)}
```

[Demo dialog screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vd9DU.png)

hope its helpful

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to the great answers - the best package I found is:

[adaptive_dialog: ^1.8.0+1](https://pub.dev/packages/adaptive_dialog)

For a one OK button the best thing I found is using `showOkAlertDialog`

Implementation:

```
import 'package:adaptive_dialog/adaptive_dialog.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Container(
        child: Center(
            child: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.info,
          ),
          onPressed: () => showOkAlertDialog(
            context: context,
            okLabel: 'OK',
            title: 'Title',
            message: 'This is the message',
          ),
        )),
      );
    }
```

Clean and dismisses when you click 'Ok'.

Answer (score 1):

**Simple and working solution that I used:** *Enjoy*
// Sample can be used for exit dialog box on apps

showAlertDialog(BuildContext context) {

```
    Widget okButton = TextButton(
      child: const Text("Leave now",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),),
      onPressed: () { SystemNavigator.pop(); },
    );

    Widget nopeButton = TextButton(
      child: const Text("Stay here"),
      onPressed: () { Navigator.pop(context); },
    );

    AlertDialog alert = AlertDialog(
      title: const Text("Leave"),
      content: const Text("Are you sure you want to leave?"),
      actions: [
        nopeButton,
        okButton,
      ],
    );

    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return alert;
      },
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is working version of Bakri Bitar's answer without changing it to Stateful Widget:

```
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


class BlurryDialog extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  final String content;
  final VoidCallback continueCallBack;
  final TextStyle textStyle = const TextStyle(color: Colors.black);

  const BlurryDialog({
    Key? key,
    required this.title,
    required this.content,
    required this.continueCallBack,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BackdropFilter(
      filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 6, sigmaY: 6),
      child:  AlertDialog(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(    // This line is added
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),   // Change this value to change the corner radius
        ),
        title: Text(title, style: textStyle, textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
        content: new Text(content, style: textStyle,),
        actions: <Widget>[
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: [
              ElevatedButton(
                child: Text('Yes', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                onPressed: () {
                       continueCallBack();
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
              
                },
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 54, 139, 244),
                  foregroundColor: Colors.black,
                ),
              ),
               ElevatedButton(
                child: Text('No', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 54, 139, 244),
                  foregroundColor: Colors.black,
                ),
              ),
            ]),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

You can call it like this:

```
VoidCallback continueCallBack = () {
  Navigator.of(context).pop();
  // code on continue comes here
};

BlurryDialog alert = BlurryDialog(
  title: "Your Title",         // Provide 'title'
  content: "Your Content Text",        // Provide 'content'
  continueCallBack: continueCallBack,   // Provide 'continueCallBack'
);

showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return alert;
  },
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another easy option to show Dialog is to use [stacked_services](https://pub.dev/packages/stacked_services) package

```
 _dialogService.showDialog(
      title: "Title",
      description: "Dialog message Tex",
         );
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works and demonstrates how to obtain the button value pressed by the user:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text(_title)),
        body: const Center(
          child: MyStatelessWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatelessWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyStatelessWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextButton(
      onPressed: () {
        // set up the buttons
        Widget cancelButton = TextButton(
          child: Text("Cancel"),
          onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, 'Cancel'),
        );
        Widget continueButton = TextButton(
          child: Text("Ok"),
          onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, 'Ok'),
        );
        showDialog<String>(
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context) => AlertDialog(
            title: const Text('AlertDialog Title'),
            content: const Text('AlertDialog description'),
            actions: <Widget>[
              cancelButton,
              continueButton,
            ],
          ),
        ).then((value) => print(value));
      },
      child: const Text('Show Dialog'),
    );
  }
}
```

Pressing on Ok button. then on Cancel button print
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```dart
showDialog<String>(
  context: context,
  builder: (BuildContext context) =>
      AlertDialog(
    title: const Text(
      'Invalid Password',
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
    ),
    content:
        const Text('Create Strong Password'),
    actions: <Widget>[
      Center(
        child: TextButton(
          style: TextButton.styleFrom(
            primary: Colors.white,
            backgroundColor: Colors
                .red, // Background Color
          ),
          onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(
              context, 'Cancel'),
          child: const Text('Cancel'),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: const Text("Storage Permission Required"),
          content: const Text(
              "Please grant storage permission to download files."),
          actions: <Widget>[
            TextButton(
              // Use TextButton instead of FlatButton
              child: const Text("CANCEL"),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
            ),
            TextButton(
              // Use TextButton instead of FlatButton
              child: const Text("SETTINGS"),
              onPressed: () {
                openAppSettings(); // Open app settings
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).