# Vertically aligned FlatButtons in Alert Dialog?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to display an AlertDialog in Flutter with 3 buttons, but vertically aligned as the text of the buttons takes up too much space. So far I only get them displayed horizontally. Any idea how to solve it? The solutions from this post ([How to make an AlertDialog in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53844052/how-to-make-an-alertdialog-in-flutter)) didn't work for me, still shown horizontally.

```
  static Future<void> showLogoutAllDevicesOrOnlyThisDialog(
      BuildContext context) {
    var b1 = FlatButton(
      textColor: Colors.red,
      child: Text('Only on this device'),
      onPressed: () {
        Navigator.of(context).pop();
        RxBus.post(HideSpinnerEvent());
      },
    );
    var b2 = FlatButton(
      textColor: Colors.red,
      child: Text('On all devices'),
      onPressed: () {
        Navigator.of(context).pop();
        RxBus.post(HideSpinnerEvent());
      },
    );

    var b3 = FlatButton(
      child: Text('Cancel'),
      onPressed: () {
        Navigator.of(context).pop();
      },
    );

    return showDialog<void>(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text(''),
          content: Text(
              "Möchtest du dich auf allen Geräten abmelden oder nur auf diesem Gerät?"),
          actions: <Widget>[
            b1, b2, b3
          ],

        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
return AlertDialog(
    title: Text(''),
    content: Text("Möchtest du dich auf allen Geräten abmelden oder nur auf diesem Gerät?"),
    actions: <Widget>[
        Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
            children: <Widget>[
                b1, b2, b3
            ]
        )
    ],
```

);

Answer (score 4):

You can create your own Custom Dialog and you anything you want, like this:

```
void _showDialog() {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      barrierDismissible: false,
      builder: (context) {
        return Dialog(
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(2),
          ),
          elevation: 0,
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              horizontal: 20,
              vertical: 10,
            ),
            child: IntrinsicWidth(
              child: IntrinsicHeight(
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 10,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      "Custom Alert Dialog",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                        fontFamily: "Roboto",
                        fontSize: 18,
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 20,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      "This is a message inside your custom Alert Dialog!\nFeel free to change it to fit your needs.",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: "Roboto",
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                        fontSize: 16,
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 30,
                    ),
                    Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                          child: FlatButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              Navigator.of(context).pop();
                            },
                            child: Text("OK"),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                          child: FlatButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              Navigator.of(context).pop();
                            },
                            child: Text("Not Sure"),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                          child: FlatButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              Navigator.of(context).pop();
                            },
                            child: Text("Cancel"),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
```

Your end result would be this one:

[image: Column]

But if you're looking for a Row design, you need something like this:

```
void _showDialog() {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      barrierDismissible: false,
      builder: (context) {
        return Dialog(
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(2),
          ),
          elevation: 0,
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              horizontal: 20,
              vertical: 10,
            ),
            child: IntrinsicWidth(
              child: IntrinsicHeight(
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 10,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      "Custom Alert Dialog",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                        fontFamily: "Roboto",
                        fontSize: 18,
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 20,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      "This is a message inside your custom Alert Dialog!\nFeel free to change it to fit your needs.",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: "Roboto",
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                        fontSize: 16,
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 30,
                    ),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        FlatButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.of(context).pop();
                          },
                          child: Text("OK"),
                        ),
                        FlatButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.of(context).pop();
                          },
                          child: Text("Not Sure"),
                        ),
                        FlatButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.of(context).pop();
                          },
                          child: Text("Cancel"),
                        ),
                      ],
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
```

With this end result:

[image: Row]

Comment: YOU ARE AWESOME DEAR. THANK YOU :)

Answer (score 1):

`actionsOverflowDirection: VerticalDirection.up` will automatically makes actions list vertical if it not fits in the row

```dart
AlertDialog(
  title: const Text('AlertDialog Title'),
  content: const Text('AlertDialog description'),
  scrollable: true,
  actionsOverflowDirection: VerticalDirection.up,
  actions: <Widget>[
    TextButton(
      onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, 'Cancel'),
      child: const Text('Save'),
    ),
    TextButton(
      onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, 'Cancel'),
      child: const Text('Cancel'),
    ),
    TextButton(
      onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, 'OK'),
      child: const Text('OK'),
    ),
    TextButton(
      onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, 'Cancel'),
      child: const Text('Delete'),
    ),
  ],
)
```

[[image: VerticalDirection of Action Widgets][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dW9G5.png)