# How to show alertdialog when button is pressed?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-alertdialog

Following is the part of my homepage.dart which is running fine but on click of IconButton nothing happens.

```
 ...
 return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('Lorem Ipsum'),
    leading: IconButton(      
      icon: Icon(Icons.info),
      onPressed: () => AboutWidget(),
    ),
  ),
  body: ...
```

This is my about_widget.dart file where my AboutWidget is defined.
What am i doing wrong?

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class AboutWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      title: Text('data'),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to call `showDialog` function

```
AppBar(
  title: Text('Lorem Ipsum'),
  leading: IconButton(
    icon: Icon(Icons.info),
    onPressed: () => showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => AboutWidget(),
    ),
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use Flutter native [`showDialog`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showDialog.html) function to show a dialog.

For your code, you could try this:

```
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('Lorem Ipsum'),
    leading: IconButton(      
      icon: Icon(Icons.info),
      onPressed: () => showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context){
          return AboutWidget();
        }
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

So when the button is pressed, you should call the [`showDialog`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showDialog.html) method.

Answer (score 1):

Using some button, that also receives a *reference* to a function:

```dart
FilledButton.icon(
onPressed: () => showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (context) => CustomDialogAlert(
        title: '¿Desea proceder?',
        description:
            'Esta acción de BORRADO no puede ser deshecha.',
        buttonLeft: 'Cancelar',
        buttonRight: 'Aceptar',
        callbackFunction: _submitFormDelete)),
icon: const Icon(Icons.delete_outline_outlined),
label: const Text('Borrar')
), // FilledButton.icon
```

And a stateless class:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomDialogAlert extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  final String description;
  final String buttonLeft;
  final String buttonRight;
  final Function() callbackFunction;

  const CustomDialogAlert(
      {super.key,
      this.buttonLeft = 'Cancelar',
      this.buttonRight = 'Ok',
      required this.description,
      required this.title,
      required this.callbackFunction});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      title: Text(title),
      content: Text(description),
      actions: <Widget>[
        TextButton(
          onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, 'Cancel'),
          child: Text(buttonLeft),
        ),
        TextButton(
          onPressed: () => callbackFunction(),
          child: Text(buttonRight),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Result is:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

On press of the button you are calling `AboutWidget()`. Its a statless widget. So it needs to be build in the build method of your app.
On button click this wont show the dialog. Instead use [`showDialog`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showDialog.html) method and inside that use your alert dialog to display the dialog on the screen.